# VBA Excel copy ActiveX Spin button between cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have got 23 cells in my worksheet, where I would like to put the button with next & previous.

I have already the macro code and the button  prepared.

[image]

But it looks like it refers only to the 1st sheet.

[image]

I cannot copy and paste this spin button as I did in case of form control buttons.

I found some links here:

https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/spin-button.html

[Launch a different sheet by Spin button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18466670/launch-a-different-sheet-by-spin-button)

But they don't help me

Is there some way to speed up this?

Comment: Any reason you can't just copy and paste this spin button? You'd need to copy and paste the code for them to each sheet as well, but I don't see why that wouldn't work.

Comment: I already firued out how to copy button, although the code must be still inputted manually (at least copied) sheet by sheet.

Comment: Yes, this is how it is I'm afraid, by design the code for an ActiveX control is located on the sheet it's on. However [there is a way to add code dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41612140/automatically-add-option-private-module-to-all-modules-in-vba) but I suppose that solution could take much longer than just manually copy-pasting your code to your sheets.